# How to provide your own example data for a custom package?

Tags: packages, curated-data

A nice feature of the mathematica documentation is the copious use of `ExampleData` in illustrating functionality. I would like to provide some example data for a package I have written, but there is apparently no guidance in the docs or on the net on how to do this. Consequently, I have two related questions:

1. Is there a hook into the system's `ExampleData` function for providing your own example data? I'm thinking along the lines of the [`` ImportExport`RegisterImport[] ``](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DevelopingAnImportConverter.html) function that provides seamless integration of a custom import converter to the `Import[]` command.
2. If not, what is a good way to provide example data from a custom package? Ideally, the data would be available from the documentation browser when someone tries one of the examples.

I would prefer to package the data together with the package code, rather than store it on a remote server and access it with `Import["http://myserver.com/exampledata.zip"]`.

Comment: question 1: no. There is no such way. Concerning 2 note that one point of ExmapleData is that it is distributed *withouth* getting a new copy of Mathematica. If you'd like to store the data with your package why not make a `myData[stuff]`, add a `Format` rule and some selectors?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand this. 1) You want to deliver test data for your package 2) You want to package it with your package code. So, why don't you put this data in the same directory and `Import` it from there? `Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "testfile.xls"}]]` or so. What would an `ExampleData` version do more than that?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Well, with `ExampleData`, one does not need to know the location of the data, as in jVincent's answer below. With `Import`, you need to know the location of the data file...

Comment: ...and that can be inconvenient when you want to access a canonical or standard example of data associated with your package. When I'm learning a new function from the docs, I often open a new (unsaved) notebook, get some data with `ExampleData`, and start playing. Is there a standard directory for storing data in a package, where Mma does not need to know the path? (I see $UserBaseDirectory<>"/ApplicationData", perhaps there?)

Comment: As long as you put your data in the same folder as your notebook the above code would work wherever you would place that directory. jVincent's solution stores all the examples in your package code and they will all be in main memory after loading the package. Doesn't sound ideal to me, particularly if it would involve large data sets such as 3D objects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could simply add new definitions for `ExampleData` in your package:

```
Unprotect[ExampleData];
ExampleData[{"JxBs Package", "RandomNumberSequence"}] := {7, 5, 8, 2, 1, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1};
Protect[ExampleData];
```

Which would make it available after loading your package

```
ExampleData[{"JxBs Package", "RandomNumberSequence"}]
```

> {7, 5, 8, 2, 1, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1}

This is sort of cheating, but It will work for your code, just not with with `ExampleData`'s listing of types, and properties.

Comment: why is it cheating? I think this is perfectly fine way to do it, except that some commands like `ExampleData[]` won't list your custom data, because it gets the list directly from ``DataPaclets`ExampleDataDump`Collections``. Of course, one could easily modify it to handle these too. If the OP doesn't want to use a custom example data function, then this is a reasonable way out (although, standard warnings about modifying built-ins in a package apply and should probably be mentioned)

Comment: @R.M I called it cheating because you end up with functionality which appears like ExampleData fully handles the new data, which it of cause doesn't, maybe a different term would be more appropriate.

Comment: Well, it depends on to what extents the OP is willing to go to mimic the built-in feature. For example, the no argument definition could be modified to, say, ``ExampleData[] := DataPaclets`ExampleDataDump`Collections ~Join~ {"JxBs Package"} // Sort`` and so on... Anyway, I think we both agree that this is a reasonable way to go for the OP :)