# Creating a PolyhedronData[] structure for custom polyhedra

Tags: graphics3d, curated-data

The `PolyhedronData[]` structure is wonderfully rich.  I would like to create data for my own polyhedra, not any of the many that Mathematica provides.  Is this possible?  I wouldn't need every property, but I would like it to function the same way, e.g., `PolyhedronData["MyPolyhedron", "VertexCoordinates"]` would return a list of vertex coordinates, etc.  I can hack up `MyPolyhedronData[]`, but I would prefer to use `PolyhedronData[]` if possible.  Thanks for ideas!

Comment: Something like what was done [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9523) could be applicable to this case, I suppose.